# Problema con Android y SQL Server

Tags: android, sql

Mi aplicación desarrollada en Android Studio está conectada a una base de datos de SQL Server para mostrar cierta información. Todo funciona perfecto, pero hay un detalle que no sé si es normal o no y si no lo es no pude encontarlo en ningún lado.

La aplicación en el celular funciona perfecto mientras mi computadora donde está el SQL Server instalado está prendida, pero si mi computadora está apagada, mi aplicación crashea cuando intento llamar a la base de datos.

¿Esto es normal? Me parece raro que solo pueda usar la aplicación mientras mi computadora esté prendida. Quizás haya alguna manera de decirle a Android Studio que cuando haga la conexión, se importe la ultima versión de la Base de Datos para poder acceder a ella incluso cuando mi PC está apagada, o algo así.

Dejo el código de la conexión a la Base de Datos por las dudas:

```
package com.example.rodrigo.libros;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rodrigo.libros.Adaptador.RecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.example.rodrigo.libros.Entidad.Items;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Verbos extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerViewItem;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewVerbos;
EditText etVerbos;
Button bnMostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

    etVerbos = findViewById(R.id.etIngresar);
    bnMostrar = findViewById(R.id.bnMostrar);

    recyclerViewItem = findViewById(R.id.rvListItems);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(manager);

    bnMostrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009933"));

    bnMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<Items> completeList = new ArrayList<>();
            completeList.addAll(mostrarVerbos());
            ocultarTeclado();
            recyclerViewVerbos = new RecyclerViewAdapter((ArrayList<Items>) mostrarVerbos());
            recyclerViewItem.setAdapter(recyclerViewVerbos);
        }
    });
}

public Connection conexionBD(){
    Connection conexion = null;
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =  new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.157;" + "databaseName=Myapp;user=sa;password=123;");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return conexion;
}

public List<Items> mostrarVerbos() {
    List<Items> verbo=new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Statement st=conexionBD().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2=st.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM verbos_port WHERE verbo_por='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR verbo_esp='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR referencia='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR eu='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR tu='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR voce='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR nos='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR voces='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() + "'"
        );
        rs2.next();
        int id = rs2.getInt("id");
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM verbos_port WHERE verbo_por ='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR verbo_esp='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR referencia='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR eu='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR tu='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR voce='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR nos='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR voces='" + etVerbos.getText().toString() +
                "' OR id=" + id
        );
        while (rs.next()){
            verbo.add(new Items(rs.getString("referencia"),rs.getString("eu"), rs.getString("tu"), rs.getString("voce"),rs.getString("nos"),rs.getString("voces")));
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El verbo no existe.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return verbo;
}

private void ocultarTeclado(){
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if(view != null){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede decir que es normal ya que no estas accediendo a una base de datos que se encuentra en tu dispositivo mòvil, en realidad estas accediendo a una base remota mediante su IP, esta base de datos seguramente se encuentra en tu PC:

```
 conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.157;" + "databaseName=Myapp;user=sa;password=123;");
```

Se supone que en producciòn esta instancia de la base de datos deberìa estar siempre activa.

Si deseas leer una base de datos dentro de tu dispositivo te sugiero revisar:

[Cómo guardar datos con SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite?hl=es-419)

y ahora como parte de JetPack puedes usar [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

[Cómo guardar contenido en una base de datos local con Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room?hl=es-419)